# Custom ng-filter for matching date value in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I'm trying to create a filter that will filter items in an ng-repeat for their dates. For example, in a div title "today" only showing items where todays date is set in each items date property. I'm hoping to end up with something like this in the markup:

```
<li class="{{todo.category}}" ng-repeat="todo in todos | taskDate : today">
    {{todo.title}}
</li>
```

Example todo structure:
(dates are generated through the AngularUI bootstrap directives so not 100% on how they are formatted.)

```
$scope.todos = [
{name : 'Complete 5 tasks',
category: 'Life',
date: ''}
]
```

The method and filter I have for this at the moment are here:

```
Date.prototype.sameDay = function(d) {
    return this.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear() && this.getDate() === d.getDate() && this.getMonth() === d.getMonth();
};


app.filter("taskDate", function() {
    return function(input, date) {
        var todaysDate = new Date();
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(todo, index) {
            if (todo.date instanceof Date) {
                if (todo.date.sameDay(todaysDate)) {
                    filtered.push(todo);
                }
            } else if (todo.date == date) {
                // filtered.push(todo);
            }
        });

        return filtered;
    };
});
```

This works for displaying items with todays date when I use the following filter

```
 |taskDate
```

, but I can't figure out how to extend it to show tomorrows etc at all.

Edit: managed to get a filter to work for today, but not other dates

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Angular's native filters to help:

```
 <li class="{{todo.category}}" ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:todoFilter('today')">


$scope.todoFilter= function(date) {
    return function(todo) {
        if(date==='today' && todo.date=== $scope.todaysDate)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyrdLLro/2/)

Comment: Appreciate the reply Scott! This doesn't seem to be working for me however, I tried it for a while and couldn't get it working. I've managed to set up a filter specifically for todays date, dropped declaring them in the scope like I was, and edited my question above accordingly if you would like to take a look.

Comment: Hi, I added a working fiddle to,perhaps, better illustrate.